# разрыв соединения с удаленной базой Postgres

Tags: база-данных, postgresql

в файл **pg_hba.conf** добавил:

```
host all all 0.0.0.0/0  md5
```

файл **postgresql.conf** изменил:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

вот мой код на Python для подключения к БД, сама БД лежит на удаленном сервере Linux

```
import psycopg2

try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname='postgres',
                            user='postgres',
                            password='space',
                            host='X.X.X.X')
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
else:
    print(conn)
    conn.close()
```

И все работвает, подключение есть, но через какой-то интервал времени, когда я пытаюсь подключится снова выдает ошибку:

**connection to server at "X.X.X.X", port 5432 failed: Connection refused
Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?**

после перезагрузи:

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

все снова работает, какое то время и так постоянно, с чем это связано понятия не имею